# ftruncate trunc file in c cannot find this function

Tags: c, windows, file

I want to truncate the file something like setsizeof() with FILE *
I'm developing vs 2003 windows

```
#include <unistd.h> there's no such lib
```

how can I do it freopen() truncates all the data vut doesn't write- getting EINVAL error
some help?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_chsize function does the job better it get fd ans size to change to

Answer (score 2):

There are a number (roughly 20) of header files in the C standard and unistd is not one of them (it's a POSIX/UNIX95/UNIX98 header). So there's no requirement for a vendor to provide it. Neither C89 nor C99 have unistd as one the the mandated header files.

The easiest way to truncate a file is to reopen it in write mode (assuming you have the file name).

```
fclose (fh);
fh = fopen ("file_name", "w");
```

If all you have is the file handle, you need to use `freopen()`. You will only get `EINVAL` if the mode is incorrect. You cannot change the mode except accoording to the following table:

```
r        -> r
w a      -> a w
r+ w+ a+ -> any mode
```

See [man freopen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/freopen/) for further details.